# Comparison operators not working properly when left and right operands are not exactly the same type

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net having the variables:

```
  Dim  Value As Single = 366.93
  Dim  Value2 As Single = 366.930023
```

the statement :

```
Value < Math.Round(Value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Evaluates to True!!! But,

```
366.93 < Math.Round(Value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Evaluates to False; the expected result.

also:

```
Math.Round(Value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Gives 366.93

For me it's an absolute nonsense; why is this? Can someone give a me clue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:
My variables are of type Single and Math.Round returns Decimal so using

```
CDec(Value1) < Math.Round(Value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

will correctly evaluate to False.

Comment: There are multiple overloads for Math.Round(). It can also return a Double. If I do `Dim x =  Math.Round(Value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` the VS debugger showed me a Double.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round()` returns a type `decimal`.  So comparing that with a type `Single` will return false because of what's called floating point precision. Reference this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) page for more info.  The reason your second expression works as expected is because of .NET's type inference. It's automatically compiling `366.93` as a decimal.

So, you can either declare your variables as a decimal?

```
Dim value as Decimal = 366.93
```

or convert the `Single` at test time.

```
If CDec(value) < Math.Round(Value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) Then
   //true
Else
   //false
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran the following code for fun:

```
Dim a As Single = 366.93
Dim b As Single = 366.930023
Dim c As Double = 366.93
'Inferred result type
Dim r1 = Math.Round(b, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
' Forced *conversion* back to Single
Dim r2 As Single = r1

Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(r1)  :  {0}", (a.Equals(r1)))
Console.WriteLine("a.Equals(r2)  :  {0}", (a.Equals(r2)))
Console.WriteLine("a < r1        :  {0}", a < r1)
Console.WriteLine("a < r2        :  {0}", a < r2)
Console.WriteLine("r1.Equals(r2) :  {0}", r1.Equals(r2))
Console.WriteLine("r2.Equals(r1) :  {0}", r2.Equals(r1))
Console.WriteLine("r1 < r2       :  {0}", r1 < r2)
Console.WriteLine("r2 < r1       :  {0}", r2 < r1)
Console.WriteLine("r1            :  {0}", r1)
Console.WriteLine("r2            :  {0}", r2)
Console.WriteLine("r1 Type       :  {0}", r1.GetType())
Console.WriteLine("a < c         :  {0}", a < c)
```

And got the following results:

```
a.Equals(r1)  :  False  
a.Equals(r2)  :  True
a < r1        :  True
a < r2        :  False
r1.Equals(r2) :  False
r2.Equals(r1) :  False
r1 < r2       :  False
r2 < r1       :  True
r1            :  366.93
r2            :  366.93
r1 Type       :  System.Double
a < c         :  True
```

While the math seems... strange, it's not entirely unexpected. `System.Single` and `System.Double` are not the same type. As with all floating-point types they are *approximations* of the exact value (try playing with `.1` now and then). When comparing different types, you must *convert* from one type to the other so you can make an equivalent comparison. That conversion especially is prone to rounding error.

Whenever comparing two floating-point values of any type, the proper procedure is to use a small value ([epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)) as a sort of fudge factor, in order to account for the lack of perfect precision. You can get an idea of how much error you've accumulated with a subtraction operation:

```
Math.Abs(a - Math.Round(b, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
```

Gives me `7.32421875682121E-06`

But of course the subtraction itself is not perfect and introduces more error. This gives you *indication of* the degree of error in the process, but not the exact error.

It's also worth noting here that `Single.Epsilon` and `Double.Epsilon` are respective to their individual types. This is a different kind of epsilon from the machine error epsilon for floating-point error. The machine epsilon is approximately `1.11E-16`, and one epsilon is rarely sufficient to describe all of the error in a complex calculation or conversion. Rather than the machine epsilon, you want a value consistent with your problem space.

In this case, the problem space is only 2 decimal places deep. We can use a value as large half of the smallest two-decimal value (`.005`) and still get good results:

```
Math.Abs(a - Math.Round(b, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)) < .005
```